# Easymock.expect throws IllegalStateException

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I see that in this piece of code,

```
expect(myService.getAll(anyBoolean())).andReturn(objectList).anyTimes();
replay(scopeService);
```

That expect statement statement is throwing 
`IllegalStateException - missing behavior definition for the preceding method call:
myService.getAll(true)
Usage is: expect(a.foo()).andXXX()`

I understand that if it throws this exception if I dont have the andReturn, or if I missed calling the  replay, or if my object is not a mock. I have checked all of that and it is not the case! Can someone please let me know if something else could be wrong?
I have around a 50 expect/replays before and nothing has an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided more code so I assume that your code looks like this more or less:

```
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.*;

public class SomeTests {
    static class Foo {
        public List<Integer> getAll(boolean value) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }

    public void someTestCase() {
        Foo mock = createMock(Foo.class);
        List<Integer> ret = Collections.singletonList(1);
        expect(mock.getAll(anyBoolean())).andStubReturn(ret);
        replay(mock);

        mock.getAll(true); // returns a list with single element 1 rather than throwing an exception
    }
}
```

my advice is that:

1. Check if `myService` instance is created by one of mocking methods
2. Reply should be called on `myService` as it switches mode of a mock

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. The issue was that the mock myService was being used to create the object that was being tested(since it has it as a member) and to create another mock object needed for the tests. 
When I changed them to use two different myService(myService, myService1) it worked! I am not sure how that would help, but it did!